# JS Fine in FF, bugged in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-chrome

I built a page that uses a simple JSon table and JS/JQ to present that data. Hosted together on one sheet it works fine in both Chrome and FF. Split into seperate HTML, CSS, JS and JSON files, however, there is a slightly variable bug in Chrome.

Page: http://www.lafairclough.co.uk/JTest/index.html

Select two options from the drop down and the charts on the right should show the relative performance data from two cars (top to bottom: 0-60, 0-100, Standing Qtr and Top Speed). These are colour coded with green being the faster result and orange denoting a draw for a given variable.

The charts are made using Java to calculate and set a CSS div width. In Chrome, however, this div width is (sometimes, but often) getting calculated as a much higher figured than expected. As flows:

```
    // Perf. BAR CHART SIZE CSS CAR A
    $.getJSON("cars.json", function (data) {

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#dropdown1').change(function () {
                var index = parseInt($(this).val()),
                    html = "<p class=\"barText\">" + " " + data.carList[index].model + " " + data.carList[index].variant + "</p>";
                $(".carA060").html(html);
                var index = parseInt($(this).val());
                var num = data.carList[index].zero60 * 10;
                $(".carA060").css('width', num + '%').show();
                html = "<p class=\"barText\">" + " " + data.carList[index].model + " " + data.carList[index].variant + "</p>";
                $(".carA0100").html(html);
                var index = parseInt($(this).val());
                var num = data.carList[index].zero100 * 5;
                $(".carA0100").css('width', num + '%').show();
                html = "<p class=\"barText\">" + " " + data.carList[index].model + " " + data.carList[index].variant + "</p>";
                $(".carAsQTR").html(html);
                var index = parseInt($(this).val());
                var num = data.carList[index].sQTR * 5;
                $(".carAsQTR").css('width', num + '%').show();
                html = "<p class=\"barText\">" + " " + data.carList[index].model + " " + data.carList[index].variant + "</p>";
                $(".carAvMAX").html(html);
                var index = parseInt($(this).val());
                var num = data.carList[index].vMAX * 0.5;
                $(".carAvMAX").css('width', num + '%').show();
            });

        });

    });
```

Any idea as to why it's going awry in Chrome would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks,

Lee.

Comment: when using `parseInt()` add the base value too: `parseInt($(this).val(), 10)`

Comment: Also could you please include to your question error from browser console?

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.5? Can't you upgrade to an higher and better version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your are passing 14.6 ( the mazda ) in your json and multiplying it by 10 for the width so thats why you are
out of bound of container change the logic of the calculation of the width and you will be fine. and the reason why in fire fox its ok and chrome not is because each browser parse the CSS differently . hope this helped

Comment: Thank you! You're absolutely right, I'd got two sets of logic in their for changing the CSS widths. Firefox was using the working one and Chrome was using another one with the math error you pointed out. Much appreciated, I thought I was going mad! Turns out I just need more sleep :D